# "Not to have been asked" vs "not being asked"- what's the difference?

Tags: participles

Sentence Transformation:

> She will be upset **that she wasn't** asked.

The answer to this statement is as follows:

> She will be upset **not to have been** asked.

Could this also be possible?

> She will be upset **not having been** asked.

What's the difference?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the third is ungrammatical but would be grammatical with "at" after "upset".

"Upset" can take three frames:

> upset that
>
> upset at/about
>
> upset

As is often the case, any difference in meaning among these very slight indeed.

  -

Answer (score 0):

For all practical purposes, there is no difference and all three examples are acceptable American English usage. I usually prefer brevity and clarity, so I would say,

**"She will be upset that she wasn't asked,"** or

**"She will be upset that she wasn't invited,"** (but only if that doesn't change the meaning).